# Swift Autofill Password not working: "failed to approve"

Tags: swift, aasa

I want to implement Password Autofill but I do not get it working. It fails with the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25293 ""beezleapp.com" failed to approve "N4EV3W64CV.com.beezleapp.beezle"" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription="beezleapp.com" failed to approve "N4EV3W64CV.com.beezleapp.beezle"}
```

For this code:

```
SecAddSharedWebCredential(
       "beezleapp.com" as CFString,
        emailPw.email as CFString,
        pw
    )
```

This are my associated domains:

[image]

Bundle identifier:

[image]

Team ID:

[image]

This is my AASA file:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "N4EV3W64CV.com.beezleapp.beezle",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  },
   "webcredentials":{
      "apps":[
         "N4EV3W64CV.com.beezleapp.beezle"
      ]
   },
   "appclips":{

   }
}
```

It is available at:

```
$ curl https://beezleapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
$ curl https://beezleapp.com/apple-app-site-association
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems your `apple-app-site-association` file has a file extension of `.p7c`. According to the documentation it **shouldn´t** have a file extension.

Comment: @burnsi as far as I can see I don't have a file extension, why do you think I have one?

Comment: Calling `https://beezleapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` downloads a file with `.p7c` extension.

Comment: @burnsi this is really strange indeed, it really does NOT have a file extension on the server. I don't really know if it is a problem, https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator return OK and `curl -i https://beezleapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` shows that the content type is configured correctly: `Content-type: application/pkcs7-mime`

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) it should be `application/json`. You could at least give it a try.

Comment: @burnsi Thanks for your help. I changed it to application/json, no more .p7c file is being downloaded :) however, the problem still persists >.<

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a DNS caching issue on the device side. I turned on `Associated Domains Development` in Settings -> Developer. Then it worked instantly.